# How to make a top bar slide down by pulling a button?

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I can't find a script or example of this... I'd like to have a little div on top of window, when you hover on it, a top horizontal bar slides down. I've made a schema :

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check the fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EghgN/8/

You can add your menu contents to the structure.